# Memory Barriers and Relaxed Memory Models

Tags: memory-barriers

Currently I try to improve my understanding of memory barriers, locks and memory model.

As far as I know there exist four different types of relaxations, namley
Write -> Read, Write -> Write, Read -> Write and Read -> Read.
An x86 processor allows just Write->Read relaxation which is often called Total Store Order (TSO).
Partial Store Order (PSO) allows further Write->Write relaxations and Relaxed Store Order (RSO)
allows all the above relaxations.

Further there exist three types of memory barriers: release, acquire and both together.
Locks can use just acquire and release barriers or sometimes full barriers (.Net).

Now consider the following example:

```
// thread 0
x = 1
flag = 1

//thread 1
while (flag != 1);
print x
```

My current understanding tells me, that I need no additional memory barriers if I run this code on 
TSO machine.
If it is a PSO machine I need a release barrier between x=1 and flag = 1 to ensure
that thread 1 gets the actual value of x if flag =1.
If it is a RSO machine I need further a acquire barrier between while(flag != 1); and print x to prevent
that thread 1 reads the value of x to early.

Are my observations correct?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your code sample is close to one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250154/understanding-non-blocking-thread-synchronization-and-thread-memorybarrier)

That said for RSO you need more memory barriers than you describe, more specifically for example one that provides freshness guarantee for thread 1 before while.

I am unsure about TSO and PSO part, hope this can be helpful cause I was also trying to understand memory barriers in that question and a couple of related ones

Answer (score 0):

Reordering can happen on both software (compiler) and hardware level. So keep that in mind. So even though on TSO CPU the 2 stores would not be reordered, there is nothing that prevents the compiler to reorder the 2 stores (or the 2 loads). So `flag` needs to be a synchronization variable and the store of `flag` needs to be a release store and the load of `flag` needs to be an acquire load.

But if we assume that the above code represents X86 instructions:

Then with TSO the above will work correctly since it will prevent the 2 stores and the 2 loads from being reordered.

But with PSO the above could fail because the 2 stores could be reordered.

So imagine you would have the following:

```
b = 1
x = 1
flag = 1
```

Whereby `b` is a value on the same cache line as `flag`. Then with write coalescing, the `flag=1` and `b=1` could be coalesced and as a consequence `flag=1` could overtake the `x=1` and hence become globally visible before the `x=1`.