# Understanding non blocking thread synchronization and Thread.MemoryBarrier

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In this threading online book:  http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

theres an example of `Thread.MemoryBarrier()`

```
   class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }

  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

We got a discussion whether there is any thread blocking going on or not?

Im thinking there is some, especially given that

> A full fence takes around ten nanoseconds on a 2010-era desktop.

On other hand, full fence is only supposed to `disable instructions reodering and caching` which by its sound doesn't qualify as thread blocking, (unlike `lock` where its clear that thread waits for other to release lock before it continues, and is blocked during that time)

About that thread 'block state'. im talking not in terms of whether thread is put into **blocked** state or not, but whether there is some thread synchronization happening, which means one thread is not able to run while other isn't letting it to do so, by means of MemoryBarrier in this case.

Also Id like to get clear understanding what each barrier achieves. For example Barrier 2 - how exactly it provides freshness guarantee and how is it connected to barrier 3? If someone would explain in detail whats each barrier purpose here( what could possibly go wrong if 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 weren't there) I think id improve my understanding of this greatly.

**EDIT:** its mostly clear now what 1, 2, and 3 do. However what 4 does that 3 doesn't is still unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that instructions take time to execute does *not* imply that a thread is blocked. A thread is blocked when it is specifically put into a blocked state, which `MemoryBarrier()` does not do.

The processor instructions that actually prevent instruction reordering and cache flushing take time, because they must wait for the caches to become coherent again. During that time, the thread is still considered running.

**Update**: So let's take a look at what's actually happening in the example, and what each memory barrier actually does.

As the link says, 1 and 4 ensure that the correct answers are produced. That's because 1 ensures that the answers are flushed into memory, and 4 ensures that the read caches are flushed prior to retrieving the variables.

2 and 3 ensure that if `A` runs first, then `B` will *always* print the answers. Barrier 2 ensures that the write of `true` is flushed to memory, and barrier 3 ensures that the read cahces are flushed before testing `_complete`'s value.

The cache and memory flushing should be clear enough, so let's look at instruction reordering. The way the compiler, CLR and CPU know they can reorder instructions is by analyzing a set of instructions in sequence. When they see the barrier instruction *in the middle of a sequence*, they know that instructions *can't* move across that boundary. That ensures that in addition to cache freshness, the instructions occur in the correct order.

Comment: sure it doesn't imply that directly, I just thought it might be considered as an evidence, its logical that command takes time to execute.

Comment: @Valentin It could be considered evidence, but it's just not the case here :)

Comment: okay, see my edit in the end of question, and while we are at it, does lock statement put a thread into blocked state (just to clarify that thread blocked state definition)?

Comment: @Valentin If a thread attempts to `lock` on an object which is already locked by another thread, then it will block.

Comment: oh great so b2 forces it to flush and not possibly delay that to some time later, makes much more sense to me now , thanks.

Comment: Hmm, so why isn't B3 enough , we cleared the cache already so both values should be read correctly,and I don't think reordering can be a problem here, in an IF statement (obvious first read is executed before second always , or?) If we ever read complete==true b1 has always executed, which means answer was written, and b3 ensured that cache was clear.

Comment: Suppose you had B3, but not B2. If `A` was executed on a different core/CPU than `B`, then without B2, the `true` written to complete wouldn't be guaranteed to be in main memory, and so flushing the read caches isn't good enough, because memory would still have a stale value.

Comment: 1 2 3 are clear now, 4 is in question given that 3 supposedly does all the cache cleanup needed to read 2 values

Comment: @Valentin: MemoryBarrier 4 is guarantee that `_answer` is read from main memory rather than private cpu/core cache; at MemoryBarrier 3 we flushes that variable to cache, but that doesn't prevents the second cpu/core from read it from its own private internal cache; i.e if two different cpu(s) executes `A` and `B`, then at `A` we flushes the `_answer` to main memory using MemoryBarrier 3, but at `B` thread, it still could read `_answer` variable from the cpu 2 internal cache.. so MemoryBarrier 4 prevents that.

Comment: whole B  method is ran by 1 thread, so I still don't see what 4 does that 3 doesn't

Comment: @Valentin There's no guarantee that single thread will always be run on the same CPU. It could be moved after a context switch before reading the answer variables, which means that an additional barrier is required there.

Comment: oh well! now thats the reason for 4! could you recommend a place where I can read about it more? I was pretty sure that its guaranteed that method B is always executed by same CPU in single thread as a whole since it doesn't have any places that I could consider possible to perform context switch on..