# Trying to understand the relation between Thread.MemoryBarrier() and context switching

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, context-switch, memory-barriers

Since it appears that context switch may happen at any point in execution of instructions I am now wondering why code "in part in question" (those 2 instructions) makes sense, if context switch can happen between any instructions and we may be on different CPU core in second instruction.

```
void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      //PART IN QUESTION
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
      //END PART IN QUESTION
    }
  }
```

Description on MemoryBarrier here doesn't appear to give guarantees [MemoryBarrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx) that CPUs won't be switched after calling it.

(this is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250154/understanding-non-blocking-thread-synchronization-and-thread-memorybarrier))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What guarantees that context-switch will not happen after Thread.MemorryBarrier() call?

Nothing. MemoryBarriers does not prevent context switching, (or atomic execution of your code).

As to your other question, why Barrier 4 is needed:

In the example code from the previous question, the C# compiler, CLR or the CPU might reorder reading of the answer variable before the completed variable if barrier 4 was not there. i.e. the code that actually runs could be similar to:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
int tmpanswer = _answer;
if (_complete)
{

  Console.WriteLine (tmpanswer);
}
```

A barrier before the Console.WriteLine() will prevent reading `_answer` before reading `_completed`

But keep in mind that the code example only provides this one guarantee about the code in void B() (provided A() is run only *once* )

- If the _complete variable is true , then Console.WriteLine will write out 123 and not 0.

So, unless A and B are run serially, the code does not provide any locking/notification such that B will always print 123. A() and B() could be interleaved/interrupted any time in its execution - you have no control over who gets to run when.

There is no guarantee that B() runs after A(), no matter which order you started the 2 threads in. (Though somewhere else in the code , you could start A() first and wait explicitly for it to finish before starting B() ofcourse)

Comment: ive thought reodering can happen if instructions are on same logical level like {a=b; c=d; d=e;} not in IF like here, where it appears logical to always first read complete, because in many cases answer won't be needed. Are you sure such reodering is possible?

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub memory access reordering has nothing to do with the logical/block levels of your C# code.

Answer (score 3):

There are no guarantees that a context switch will or won't happen around a `MemoryBarrier`.  These are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: well could you elaborate a little? if you look at the linked question there are 2 memorybarrier calls in B method, and its said that second one is needed to ensure that we disable caching before reading the answer variables in case context switch happens, but if they are orthogonal I am thinking barrier 3 should be enough then or?...

Comment: They are just different concepts. MemoryBarrier's are fences which just limit the ability read and write instructions to be reordered.  They simply can't jump over the fence.  A context switch is just changing what thread is currently running.  It can happen immediately before or after a barrier (or really at any time it pleases).

Comment: If you need to protect a variable against multiple readers/writers, then I suggest using a `lock`.

Comment: this makes sense to me, but when you look at the linked question there is a memory barrier call 3 that disables instructions reordering already, and that method is only reading, not writing, and theres an  if why isn't it enough then , and mb4 call is needed? Or it is possible that read of answer happens before read of complete, if MB4 is not there?? that would be news to me.

Comment: @ sixlettervariables im trying to understand memorybarrier , lock is fairly straightforward , unlike barrier , to me

Comment: @Valentin memory barriers are hard to summarize up in full on a SO post. In short though from your perspective the compiler / CPU can reorder read and writes instructions within a certain set of rules.  i.e. if read A and write B are unrelated they can execute in either order (read / write or write / read).  A memory barrier prevents reordering to cross it.  So read A, memory barrier, write B will force it to execute in read A, then write B.  This can be imporant for certain types of algorithms (most notably lock free ones)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me Jared. But now that ive edited question, can you say how MB4 helps the code in a way that MB3 doesn't? I think that can be answered in SO post. In my original question im told its because we need to clear cache before reading answer, in case context switch happened between IF and CONSOLE calls, but if concepts are orthogonal MB3 call should be enough already

Comment: @Valentin i've read both your question and the referenced blog post. It's really unclear what's tring to be achieved in the blog post and hence hard to understand why they needed the memory barriers.

Comment: I think goal was to provide atomicity of A and B methods, we either 1)read complete==true AND have correct answer, or 2) we read not complete and don't check for answer, depending on which thread A or B executed first, if that was undefined ( using Parallel.Invoke(A,B) for example)

Comment: @Valentin i'm not sure if I agree with the sample. I would believe only one of the barriers is needed (after write to `_answer`). The rest are superfluous. The freshness argument is wishy washy IMOH. I'd have to read more about it.

Comment: Barrier 1 is needed to prevent \_completed being written before \_answer. Barrier 4 is needed to read \_completed before \_answer.  Barrier 3 is of very questionable value. I'd be a tad surprised if a thread finishing doesn't cause a memory barrier too in C#. If it doesn't the reason for Barrier 2(which would sync caches, not needed on x86, but needed on itanium) would be that if you somewhere explicitly run A first in one thread, wait for it to finish, then run B, then B would see the updated values.

Comment: @Lyke ah yes on Barrier #4. I constantly forget about the read-reordering problem.